# User configured VIEW fields

Tags: views

Curious, is there a module or technique I can use to easily allow my clients (who log in with a limited role) to manage fields visible in any given view?

Actually there are two specific content types and two specific page views -- which I would love to give them the capability to customize to their liking.

Comment: Are you talking about views as in Views module or viewing a single node? And do you want them to be able to edit the fields of the content type or edit how the view displays the fields? Can you add an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something you can do with [Views Dynamic Fields](https://drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields). Unfortunately there's only a D6 release atm, but perhaps you can port the module to D7 when it seems to fit your needs.